# How to get a subquery total in SSRS

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, ssrs-2012

I'm new to SSRS because I'm needing to do some more complex reports that are getting increasingly difficult/impossible in Crystal Reports.  The initial report I'm working on involves getting a Trailing-Three-Month total for sales by salesperson grouped by week.  Given a date range and a selected salesperson, I can get the basic report done with total sales grouped by year and week number (1-52).

However, for each of those weeks, I need to get the total sales for the 13-week period ending with that week.  For example, for week # 20 - I need to show the total sales for weeks 8-20.  On week # 21, I need to show the total sales for weeks 9-21.  Etc.

I've managed to do some date formulas to calculate the starting & ending dates of the three month period.  But what is the preferred way to get the subtotal of sales into the main report?  In Crystal Reports, there was a way to pass a value from a subreport into the main report.  But from what I understand, you can't do that in SSRS - subreports are "display only".  Eventually, I will need to graph the TTM amount.

I've tried several methods, but I want to know what the best way is to get these kind of values?  If I were writing code, it would just be nesting Do-While loops.  What is the best method as far as complexity and/or performance?

Comment: Welcome to SO check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),  It is unclear if you need a subreport or not. I think your requeriment is achievable but it is necessary you reduce your question to a specific issue.

Comment: Thanks...I'm just looking for the best method to do it.  From what I've read, it cannot be done with a subreport. (But I'm new to SSRS, so what do I know?)  The specific issue is "What is the best way to get a subtotal from a second query?"

Comment: What do you mean with second query?

Comment: For each "Week" grouping in my report, I need to go out and add up the total sales from the previous 12 weeks.  It's a subquery that would run for each group.

Comment: Yes, I'd create a main report showing all weeks numbers. For every week number set a link to a subreport and passes the week number. In subreport show the data for the 12 previous weeks to the passed week. Check [this](http://www.sql-datatools.com/2015/06/SQL-SSRS-Drill-through-Report.html)

Comment: Right...I can do that.  Now the problem is - how do I get the total from the subreport into the main report?  I would like to graph the subreport totals from each week in the main report.

Comment: Does anybody else have any ideas on this?  I still haven't been able to figure it out.